# How to use if/else condition in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In selenium webdriver i want to use if/else condition with java. Each steps need to be checked and need to execute one by one. For example

```
Log.info("Clicking on Reports link");
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("reports"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

In this code, i need to check the id once it present it need to perform the action else it need to skip the test case  not to be failed.

Comment: Am using TestNg framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(driver.findElement(By.id("reports").size()!=0){

   WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("reports"));
   actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();

   }
   else{
   system.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");

}
```

use this one -- if the element is not persent also testcase doesnt fail

Comment: I have tried all the above methods but the problem when i change the ID and checked it is not throwing exception or else part it is showing                                                        Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 32 milliseconds                                                        And the test case is failed

Comment: Here is the HTML tag <a id="reports" class=" parentMenu active" name="reports" href="https://10.4.16.159/reports/">Reports</a>

Answer (score 2):

**Option #1:**

```
WebElement menuHoverLink = null;
try
{
    menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("reports"));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
if (menuHoverLink != null)
{
    actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
    Thread.sleep(6000);
}
```

**Option #2:**

```
List<WebElement> menuHoverLinks = driver.findElements(By.id("reports"));
if (menuHoverLinks.size() > 0)
{
    actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLinks.get(0)).perform();
    Thread.sleep(6000);
}
```

**Keep in mind that `Thread.sleep` by itself may also throw an exception, so you should either catch it inside the method, or add `throws Exception` at the end of the method's declaration.**

Comment: There's one thing I would like to change in your Option #1. Inside catching all the exception, why not just catch ElementNotFound exception? Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this one . i think this should work 
for me it worked 

private boolean existsElement(String id) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.id(id));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("id is not present ");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


if(existsElement("reports")==true){

   WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("reports"));
   actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();

   }
   else{
   system.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch block in your script like

```
Log.info("Clicking on Reports link");
try {
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("reports"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
Thread.sleep(6000);
} Catch(Exception e) {
// Element not found....do not fail my test
}
```

Comment: Will not work correctly if one of the `action` methods throws an exception (I'm not sure if they do), or if `Thread.sleep` throws an exception (I know for sure that it might). OP should put only the `driver.findElement` method call inside the `try/catch` block.